# Serverside send information to vanilla HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, express

Is it possible to send information from the serverside to the client side like you would with Pug or EJS but without a view engine?

Right now I am using XHTTP requests to access data but it would be a lot easier to not have to use it so much.

```
function getAllBears(id){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("allBear").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "allBears", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert a script tag in HTML and stringify the variable you have on server side, then read the serialized global variable on window.

response.body = ('

```html
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
    <p>text...</p>
    <script>
        window.bar = @@@
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

'.replace(@@@, JSON.stringify(bar))

Be careful that some patterns/chars should be replaced in the result of `JSON.stringify`, a much safer method is as follows:

```js
function toJSONSafely (obj: any) {
    return JSON.stringify(obj)
        .replace(/\u2028/g, '\\u2028')
        .replace(/\u2029/g, '\\u2029')
        .replace(/<\/script>/g, '<\\/script>')
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that you write the HTML as a string, not a file?

Comment: Yes, but you can also save it as file and read it by `fs.readFileSync`

Answer (score 0):

User your javascript inside the html code i.e inline javascript
as shown below

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>use this code </p>
    <script>
        function getAllBears(id){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("allBear").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "allBears", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```